# Failed to get AWS Cloud Provider. GetCloudProvider returned <nil> instead

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyterhub, amazon-ebs, amazon-efs

I have a hand-built Kubernets cluster 1.11.4 using CentOS running as AWS ec2 instances, 1 master and 1 minion.  The cluster is very stable.  I'm want to deploy JupyterHub into the cluster.  The doc  [here](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/amazon/efs_storage.html#amazon-efs) and [here](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-storage.html#user-storage) call out some details for provisioning EFS.  I elected to go with EBS.

The pvc fails with:

```
Failed to get AWS Cloud Provider. GetCloudProvider returned <nil> instead
Mounted By:  hub-76ffd7d94b-dmj8l
```

Below is the StorageClass definition:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: gp2
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
  fsType: ext4
```

The pv yaml:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: jupyterhub-pv
  labels:
    type: amazonEBS
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 30Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  awsElasticBlockStore:
    volumeID: vol-0ddb700735db435c7
    fsType: ext4
```

The pvc yaml:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: jupyterhub-pvc
  labels:
    type: amazonEBS
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

```
$ kubectl -n jhub describe pvc hub-db-dir
```

returns:

```
Name:          hub-db-dir
Namespace:     jhub
StorageClass:  standard  <========from an earlier try
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        app=jupyterhub
               chart=jupyterhub-0.8.2
               component=hub
               heritage=Tiller
               release=jhub
Annotations:   volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Events:
  Type       Reason              Age                     From                         Message
  ----       ------              ----                    ----                         -------
  Warning    ProvisioningFailed  110s (x106 over 3h43m)  persistentvolume-controller  Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "standard": Failed to get AWS Cloud Provider. GetCloudProvider returned <nil> instead
Mounted By:  hub-76ffd7d94b-dmj8l
```

To me, this looks like an attempt by the pod to mount the storage, but fails.  And isolating this error has been a challenge.  I tried patching the pvc to update the storageclass to `gp2`, which is now marked as default, but was not at the time I deployed the pvc policy.  Patching failed:

```
$ kubectl -n jhub patch pvc hub-db-dir -p '{"spec":{"StorageClass":"gp2"}}'
persistentvolumeclaim/hub-db-dir patched (no change)
```

```
$ kubectl -n jhub describe pvc hub-db-dir
Name:          hub-db-dir
Namespace:     jhub
StorageClass:  standard  <====== Not changed
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        app=jupyterhub
               chart=jupyterhub-0.8.2
               component=hub
               heritage=Tiller
               release=jhub
Annotations:   volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Events:
  Type       Reason              Age                      From                         Message
  ----       ------              ----                     ----                         -------
  Warning    ProvisioningFailed  2m26s (x108 over 3h48m)  persistentvolume-controller  Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "standard": Failed to get AWS Cloud Provider. GetCloudProvider returned <nil> instead
Mounted By:  hub-76ffd7d94b-dmj8l
```

JupyterHub deployment is managed by Helm/tiller, so when any changes are made, I use the following to update the pods:

```
$ helm upgrade jhub jupyterhub/jupyterhub --version=0.8.2 -f config.yaml
```

The relevant section in the config.yaml file to allocate user storage is:

```
proxy:
  secretToken: "<random value>"
singleuser:
  cloudMetadata:
    enabled: true
singleuser:
  storage:
    dynamic:
      storageClass: gp2
singleuser:
  storage:
    extraVolumes:
      - name: jupyterhub-pv
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: jupyterhub-pvc
    extraVolumeMounts:
      - name: jupyterhub-pv
        mountPath: /home/shared
```

Part of the troubleshooting has also focused on letting the cluster know that its resources are provisioned by AWS.  To that end, I have in the kubernets config file:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
```

the line:

```
Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--cloud-provider=aws --cloud-config=/etc/kubernetes/cloud-config.conf
```

where: `/etc/kubernetes/cloud-config.conf` contains:

```
[Global]
KubernetesClusterTag=kubernetes
KubernetesClusterID=kubernetes
```

In the files `kube-controller-manager.yaml` and `kube-apiserver.yaml` I added the line:

```
- --cloud-provider=aws
```

I have not yet tagged any AWS resources, but will start doing it based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458753/kubernetes-on-aws-cloud-provider).

What are my next next steps for troubleshooting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be [this](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2018/09/28/setting-up-the-kubernetes-aws-cloud-provider/) link can help?

> You must have the `--cloud-provider=aws` flag added to the Kubelet
>   before adding the node to the cluster. Key to the AWS integration is a
>   particular field on the Node object—the `.spec.providerID` field - and
>   that field will only get populated if the flag is present when the
>   node is added to the cluster. If you add a node to the cluster and
>   then add the command-line flag afterward, this field/value won’t get
>   populated and the integration won’t work as expected. No error is
>   surfaced in this situation (at least, not that I’ve been able to
>   find).
>
> If you do find yourself with a missing `.spec.providerID` field on the
>   Node object, you can add it with a kubectl edit node command. The
>   format of the value for this field is
>   `aws:///<az-of-instance>/<instance-id>`.

Comment: Thank you, Vasily.  When I do an edit, I don't find the pattern providerID.  I tried:

Comment: ```spec: {}
status:
  addresses:
  - address: 172.31.24.144
    type: InternalIP
  - address: k8s4-node.aws-intanalytic.com
    type: Hostname
  -providerID:
    aws: ///<us-east-1a>/<i-0fd4210e519ad21bf>```

Comment: Looks like comments ignore markdown.  It failed.  But, I'm not clear on the syntax needed to make the change.  Where can I find an example.

Comment: Removed the curly braces and added ```spec:
  providerID: aws:///<us-east-1a>/<i-0fd4210e519ad21bf>```  The edit was accepted.  However, after doing a helm/tiller update, I get the same error.